# Adding red marker to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the below code to generate a Google Map for the footer navigation of my website and would like to add a red pin to its lat/long but can't seem to figure it out. This method of adding the Google Map seems to strip the red marker and also provides a nicer, more elegant UI as opposed to the default one as per the Google Maps page.

The HTML

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:295px;height:210px;"></div>
```

The Javascript

```
    <!-- Script for Google Maps UI -->
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
    function initialize()
    {
      var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.790320,-117.099955),
        zoom:12,
        disableDefaultUI:false,    
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

See here for live example of map: http://web.n8geeks.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

So add this after your var map = .... Line

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.790320,-117.099955),
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

This and  the link above should get you what you need

Comment: Perfect. I couldn't find that page for the life of me.